# JQuery Not Found

Tags: jquery, file, upload, blueimp

I received a Jquery NOT Found error
jquery.min.js:4 POST /uploadphoto 404 (Not Found) 
Though the JQuery is included as
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js

I use the demo sample to create a Java uploadphoto in the back end, and modified the demo.js action as

```
  $('#fileupload').fileupload({
    // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
    //xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
    url: '/uploadphoto'
  });

)
```

Comment: This may be possible due to not having any handler for POST request on `/uploadphoto`.

Answer (score 0):

The error is not telling you that it's not finding jQuery. The error is telling you that jQuery got a 404 response, meaning "not found" when it contacted the url 'uploadphoto'. Check that the url 'uploadphoto' actually has a POST request handdler.